# Mobilefirst Studio and Bluemix

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud

i want to ask a question concerning the integration between Bluemix platform and mobilefirst studio on my local environment. 
First i did all the steps in the following link:

http://mbaas-gettingstarted.ng.bluemix.net/hybrid

After i followed the steps i did this in my `main.js` file

```
var ibmbluemix,ibmpush;
var values = {
    applicationId: "7ecb984c-43e5-4dcab2a0-76aca303ba6d",
    applicationRoute: "http://ibm-banktrial2.mybluemix.net"
};

 function initPush() {
    ibmbluemix=IBMBluemix.hybrid;
    ibmpush = IBMPush.hybrid;
    ibmbluemix.initialize(values);
 }
```

and then i tried running the application on the android simulator and it's fine no errors happen.

what i want to do now, is that i want this application not to be locally deployed i want it deployed on bluemix, and i want to access the services for this ibm-banktrial2 app on ibmbluemix platform, it contains a service called "Business rules" and it has a rest API that i can't deal with through mobilefirst in the main.js and i couldn't find any useful links.

PS: i made the business rules service instance and i made the rules through eclipse with the plugin for business rules and i deployed it.
what i want is to validate an application request from mobilefirst to access this business rules service which contains the rules for validating a bankloan.

final note: i understood nothing from the following link:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSQP76_8.7.0/com.ibm.odm.dserver.rules.ref.res/html/restapi/html/index.html

Comment: Omar, how is this difference from your previous question about the same topic - please keep only 1 question.

Comment: but the first one didn't include the connecting to services part

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding you correctly you want the application to run on Bluemix?  It looks like you are running a hybrid app.  The code you have above runs locally on the mobile device.  Since you are running a hybrid app you can not run the above code on Bluemix.  Bluemix in this case provides a backend for your app.